# React Native AsyncStorage module causes error with spread operator ...require('React')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs, redux

When I import the AsyncStorage module (for redux-storage) I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./~/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js
Module parse failed: ~/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js Line 112: Unexpected token ...
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   // Note: this must be placed last to prevent eager
|   // evaluation of the getter-wrapped submodules above
|   ...require('React'),
| };
```

My .babelrc extends the react-native one:

```
"extends": "react-native/packager/react-packager/.babelrc"
```

I have tried reinstalling the native library but didn't help.

I am using this github starter kit https://github.com/este/este

Have checked webpack config like this issue suggested and its the same https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/f9b744d50137de25357994fe2e829f98104e2242

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It's been a while. Today I would strongly advice against using this. Just run the react-native packager. Use a .babelrc if you want to. No reason for this obscure code at all and I doubt if it still works.

---

https://gist.github.com/alexesDev/071f8935c82ca87a5b46

These are the actual pieces of the puzzle:

(check out the link for more info)

webpack.config.js;

```
var reactNativeExternalsPromise = (function () {
  var reactNativeRoot = path.dirname(require.resolve('react-native/package'));
  var blacklist = require('react-native/packager/blacklist');
  var ReactPackager = require('react-native/packager/react-packager');
  const rnEntryPoint = require.resolve('react-native');

  return ReactPackager.getDependencies({
    assetRoots: [__dirname],
    blacklistRE: blacklist(false),
    projectRoots: [__dirname],
    transformModulePath: require.resolve('react-native/packager/transformer'),
  }, {
    entryFile: rnEntryPoint,
    dev: true,
    platform: 'ios',
  })
    .then(function (dependencies) {
      return dependencies.filter(function (dependency) {
        return !dependency.isPolyfill;
      });
    })
    .then(function (dependencies) {
      return dependencies.map(function (dependency) {
        return dependency.id;
      });
    });
}());
```

and

```
externals: [
    function (context, request, cb) {
      reactNativeExternalsPromise.then(function (reactNativeExternals) {
        if (['react-native'].concat(reactNativeExternals).indexOf(request) != -1) {
          cb(null, request);
        } else{
          cb();
        }
      });
    }
  ],
```